# Coding style: function call with typed null

Tags: java, kotlin

E.g. the Java class `java.awt.image.Raster` has multiple overloaded methods, like

```
double[] getPixel(int x, int y, double[] dArray)
float[] getPixel(int x, int y, float[] fArray)
int[] getPixel(int x, int y, int[] iArray)
```

It is allowed to call the method with `null` as array but how to do it right in Kotlin?

```
val pixel = raster.getPixel(1, 2, null)
```

fails because of an ambiguity and

```
val pixel = raster.getPixel(1, 2, null as IntArray)
```

gives a warning that "This cast can never succeed".

Is there a way to call the function so that it completely pleases the compiler?

Comment: would "null as IntArray?" work?

Comment: @JesusFreke Yes, thanks. I have overseen this. If you put it in an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks, answer added. I'm not super familiar with kotlin yet, so I honestly wasn't sure that was the right answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"this cast can never succeed" is referring to the fact that IntArray is not a nullable type, and so trying to cast null to IntArray will always fail.

Since java reference types can always be null, I would expect kotlin to treat that `int[]` as an `IntArray?` (at least, in the absence of a `@Nonnull` annotation), and so `null as IntArray?` is what you want.

e.g.

`val pixel = raster.getPixel(1, 2, null as IntArray?)`